# Adding subview to UITable

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, xcode4

I'm trying to add as subview into a section in UITableView, It looks like the code is correct, the it doesn't show anything, just blank section. Here's the code that I use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(indexPath.section==0){
        cell.textLabel.text =@"<>";
    }else if(indexPath.section==1){
        if(indexPath.row==1){
            cell.frame =CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:page.view];
        } 
    } else if(indexPath.section==2){

    }


    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

Thanx in advance..

Comment: What is `page`? What's the value of `page.view.frame`?

Comment: it's a class, a class with page.xib in it.. I'm trying to add the view of the xib to the table section..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is that you are trying to change the height of the cell. If you want to do so, in addition to changing its frame, you must also implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return appropriate values for each row. If page is properly loaded (assuming it's a view controller), you can add the view as a subview. Make sure its frame falls within the bounds of the cell.

**Attaching the view**

Since `dPage` is a view controller, you will have to declare `page` as an `ivar` of class `dPage` and then do this in `viewDidAppear:`,

```
page = [[dPage alloc] initWithNibName:"page" bundle:nil];
```

and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` remains unchanged.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, since I try it out ur way, the session still blank.. I suspect the .xib is null when being call to the section.. Any way to confirm this?

Comment: I did say if the page was properly loaded. How did you load it, can you update the code?

Comment: U mean the page.xib or the mainpage.xib?

Comment: Where are you loading `page.xib` ?

Comment: I don't think I do load it, since I thought the page.xib will be automatically called when the section is called(which is the code above). Sorry if I'm wrong, since I just started learning xcode like less than a month.

Comment: What does `page.xib` contain and which class is its `File's Owner`?

Comment: page.xib contain a segmented button and a label. the file's owner is dPage.

Comment: Is `dPage` a view controller subclass?

Comment: Yep, it is.. Since it got implementation of the UIViewController next to the interface: dpage

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to load the view controller and add it as a subview.

Comment: how should I declare the page as ivar? Is it from the @property bla2 in the .h part?

Comment: `@interface ***; UITableViewController { [..] dPage *page; } [..] @end` Just declare it within the curly braces.

Comment: Nope.. Still not working.. Any other solution? Or it's just I can't add a view from other .xib to tablecell?

Comment: You can load a view from another NIB file but it seems very odd when you use a view controller for it. You should be able to create a view XIB and load it easily. There are quite a few examples out there. Let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: It's ok.. I've used another method, I create my own custom tablecell and throw anything I want there, as long as it gave me the result I want, I guess this method just fine.. Thanx for your effort..